# I am trying to load list of lists in application.yml file

Tags: yaml

```
region:
  NA:
    - envName: sandbox
      envURL: http://localhost:8010
    - envName: prod
      envURL: http://localhost:8010
  EU:
    - envName: sandbox
      envURL: http://localhost:8010
    - envName: prod
      envURL: http://localhost:8010
  LA:
    - envName: sandbox
      envURL: http://localhost:8010
    - envName: prod
      envURL: http://localhost:8010
```

This is the yaml file, which I want to load in spring boot. Can I get help how I can load this config file in spring boot? I have tried below solution but I want more in dynamic way, let's say in future one more region will get added name as "IN" it should get load automatically. Is there any way we can load it automatically if any new region will get added in yaml file?
Note: I do not want to update everytime Config class when yaml updated. It should load automatically.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("region")
public class Config {
    private List<RegionInstances> NA; 
    private List<RegionInstances> LA;
    private List<RegionInstances> EU;
    //getters and setters
    public static class RegionInstances extends HashMap<String, String>{
    private String envName;
    private String envURL;
    //getters and setters
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must work to get `NA` region:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("region")
public class Config {
    private List<Map<String, String>> NA;
}
```

Comment: But I want list of envURLs from this yaml files. And I want to dynamic logic where if i can add more regions if future, let's say "IN" then It should get load dynamically. Is there any way to do this?